# how to create columns in streamlit and plotly with python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, streamlit

I am creating a dashboard using the new web app for data science **streamlit** with coordination with **plotly**.
In streamlit there is an ability to create **Grid Layout**  by separating components with columns and you can adjust the size of the columns as you need, using this statement: `col1,col2,col3 = st.beta_columns(3)`

the problem is that when i tried this option the charts are displayed on each other like so :

[image]

**where it must display the pie chart beside the bar chart**

## code:

```
#Streamlit pckgs
import streamlit as st

# EDA pckgs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#VIZ pckgs
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

col1,col2,col3 = st.beta_columns([2,2,2])

        data = st.file_uploader("Upload Dataset",type=["csv","xlsx","xls"])
        if data is not None:        
            #check the type of the file 
            if data.type =="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":
                df=pd.read_excel(data)
            elif data.type =="application/vnd.ms-excel":
                df=pd.read_csv(data)
            
            all_columns_names = df.columns.tolist()
            col = st.selectbox("Choose Column",df.columns.tolist())
            selected_column_names__pyplot = st.multiselect("Select Columns",all_columns_names)
            plot_btn = st.button("Generate Plot")
            #count plot
            with col1:
                #pie chart
                if st.checkbox("Pie Plot"):
                    if plot_btn:
                        data_pie = df[col].value_counts().to_frame()
                        labels=data_pie.index.tolist()
                        datavals=data_pie[col].tolist()
                        
                        trace=go.Pie(labels=labels,
                                    values=datavals,
                                    hovertemplate = "%{label}: <br>Value: %{value} ",
                                    showlegend=True,
                                    textposition='inside',
                                    )
                        layout = go.Layout(
                        title = 'Percentage of {}'.format(col),
                        height=600,
                        margin=go.Margin(l=0, r=200, b=100, t=100, pad=4)   # Margins - Left, Right, Top Bottom, Padding
                        )
                        
                        data = [trace]
                        fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout = layout)
                        st.plotly_chart(fig)

            with col2:
                if st.checkbox("Count_plot"):
                    # all_columns_names = df.columns.tolist()
                    # s=df[all_columns_names[0]].str.strip().value_counts()
                    if plot_btn:
                        s=df[col].str.strip().value_counts()
                        trace  = go.Bar(
                                x=s.index,
                                y=s.values,
                                showlegend = True
                                )

                        layout = go.Layout(
                            title = 'Count of {}'.format(col),
                        )
                        data = [trace]
                        fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout = layout)
                        st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

based on the answer of---- i change this line `st.plotly_chart(fig)` to this line `st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)`

But the charts becomes very small :

**where the pie chart is in the first column
and the bar chart is in the second column**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be by creating a three-column layout where you space out the first plot (in this case 20x) to show them equally. Here is a reproducible example:

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px

# data
long_df = px.data.medals_long()

# figure
fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count",
                color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")

# plots
plot1, plot2, plot3 = st.columns((20,1,1))
plot1.plotly_chart(fig)    
plot3.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `use_container_width=True` while plotting

```
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it makes the charts very small size  i will edit my question and display the result

Comment: Try to update the width/height of the figure using  fig.update_layout(width=600,height=600) in combination with the above the changes

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

You're using `st.beta_columns()` in your code, which is deprecated and should be replaced with `st.columns()`

From my experience, sometimes specifying the chart width or height with the library you're using to create it interferes with `st.columns()` layout. Maybe try to remove the height parameter in the layout and see if `st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)` scales the charts well.

Have you tried replacing `st.columns([2,2,2])` with `st.columns(3)`? I think both should create 3 equal-width columns but maybe they interact differently with charts?